# Why is a streaming query still up and running after StreamingQueryManager.awaitAnyTermination?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to terminate the spark mapping after a specific time. I'm using `sqlContext.streams.awaitAnyTermination(long timeoutMs)` for that. But the mapping is not stopping after the given timeout.

I have tried to read from azure event hub and provided 2 min (120000 ms) as a timeout for awaitAnyTermination method. but the mapping is not stopping on azure databricks cluster.

Below is my code. I'm reading from azure eventhub and writing to console and 120000ms to awaitAnyTermination.

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._

// Event hub configurations
// Replace values below with yours
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder

val connStr = ConnectionStringBuilder()
      .setNamespaceName("iisqaeventhub")
      .setEventHubName("devsource")
      .setSasKeyName("RootManageSharedAccessKey")
      .setSasKey("saskey")
      .build

val customEventhubParameters = EventHubsConf(connStr).setMaxEventsPerTrigger(5).setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)

// reading from the Azure event hub
val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()

// write to console
val query = incomingStream.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

// awaitAnyTermination for shutting down the query
sqlContext.streams.awaitAnyTermination(120000)
```

I am expecting that mapping should have ended after a timeout. No error but mapping is not stopping.

Comment: `awaitAnyTermination` should finish itself (with a `TimeoutException`) or right after a streaming query has finished. What do you experience?

Comment: I seem to remember this from the past.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I don't see streaming query finishing. Instead of that, it is continuing for an indefinite time in azure databricks cluster.

Comment: That's a correct behaviour as `awaitAnyTermination` will simply let the current thread to continue after `1200000` ms not that it will stop any streaming query. You should stop it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Works as designed.

---

From the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager):

> **awaitAnyTermination(timeoutMs: Long): Boolean**
>
> Returns whether any query has terminated or not (multiple may have terminated).

In other words, no streaming query is going to be terminated at any point in time (before or after the `timeoutMs`) unless there is an exception or `stop`.

Answer (score 0):

When using DataBricks and prototyping, this is what I use to stop Spark Structured Streaming Apps in a separate Notebook pane:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
StreamingContext.getActive.foreach { _.stop(stopSparkContext = false) }
```